# Is it best practice to have an if - else block inside the else block

Tags: javascript

I have a Map = {'key - string', value as object} and a List[] and a String 'TEST',

Here I need to check two checking based on the String in the map and the Array,

For Example,

```
 if(Map.has('TEST')) {
      Need to do some logic
 } else {
      if(Array.includes('TEST') {
          Need to do some manipulation
      } else {
       Need to do some manipulation
      }
 }
```

I have tried like above to achieve my need. Is it a best practice? Advice me.

Comment: Use if-else ladder over nested if-else wherever possible

Comment: Regarding coding best practices I use this https://github.com/airbnb/javascript I have been following this for the past 2 years. Best resource to have at your bay.

Comment: I would usually prefer `if...else-if...else-if` instead of nesting something inside the else block, particularly to reduce the nesting (i.e. added indentation to blocks in else block).

Comment: If you're able, try `return`-ing from your `if`, then`else` is no longer needed.

Comment: I don't know why some people close this question. Do we have similar questions like this here. I searched it and after that only ask.

Comment: I don't think there is any performance issue but in this example it is more readable in if else statement. but if you want to do some thing common in first else use like this.

Comment: You might also want to read up on: [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Map.has('TEST')) {
    Need to do some logic
} else if(Array.includes('TEST')) {
    Need to do some manipulation
} else {
    Need to do some manipulation
}
```

Use `Else If`

[More Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

EDIT1: Since you said you Need to check 2 Things Maybe this suits even more but im not sure your Question is very vague.

```
// || = OR 
if(Map.has('TEST') || Array.includes('TEST')) {
    Need to do some logic
} else {
    Need to do some manipulation
}
```